# iPad and jQuery hide() on page load has big delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, ipad

I have written a bit of jQuery that hides a certain element on page load, which works seamlessly on browsers on a mac, but when I try it on the iPad there is a noticable poping of the page as the element appears and then disappears. Is this the iPad that is causing the problem, in which case I may have to rethink my page loading process.

To hide the element I am using:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#element').hide();
});
```

Other jQuery later shows the element when I click on things so I could possible hide it using css but that won't degrade nicely on the absence of js.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you just a class to the html tag right after you declare it (*with javascript*) and use CSS to hide the element ?

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.documentElement.className = 'js';
</script>
```

Css rule (*in a stylesheet, or in the head as well*)

```
.js #element{display:none;}
```

just add the above inside the page `<head>` tag and you should be set.

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/C2jdX/

Comment: @T.J Crowder i am not hiding the page. the rule is `.js #element` so it hides the specific element only. It is the fastest way to notify the DOM that JS is available, and if so use  natural means (*Css*) to hide what you want.

Comment: @Gaby: I am just so flippin' tired today. Sorry, man. With you now.

Comment: That is a genius idea! I would have never thought of that. I will try this asap

Comment: @Designer, genius indeed ! but i haven't thought about it either.. I got wind of it from the [html5 boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/)

Comment: @Gaby I have tried it and it seems to have fixed the issue so well done. Hopefully it should have no knock on effects.

Answer (score 2):

To isolate the cause, and work around it if it turns out to be intractable, you might consider hiding it using inline script just before the closing `body` tag, rather than via the `ready` handler. E.g.:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- blah blah blah -->
<script src='path_to/jquery.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- blah blah blah -->
<div id='element'>...</div>
<!-- blah blah blah -->
<script>
    $('#element').hide();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

As long as the script follows the closing of the element in question, it should be found.

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/oliki4)

I assume there's a good reason for hiding it only when scripts run (progressive enhancement, that kind of thing).

References:

- [Google Closure Library guys on why they don't need a `ready` event](http://groups.google.com/group/closure-library-discuss/browse_thread/thread/1beecbb5d6afcb41)
- [YUI's best practices](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html)

Comment: I will give this a try and see what happens.